# How do I grab multiple instances of a pattern with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby

Here is an example of the HTML I am scanning.

```
<div class="text">
 <h3>
  <a href="http://www.faith.co.uk/">
    Rodeo Sinclair
  </a>
 </h3>
.
.
.
h3>
 <a href="http://www.hate.co.uk/">
   Morvern
 </a>
</h3>
```

and here is my code.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

output = doc.css('div h3 a').attr("href")
```

The problem is, it only outputs the first url. How do I get both?

Comment: If there exist multiple instances of the pattern (`div h3 a` in your case), then `css` should return a `NodeSet` which you can iterate through.

Answer (score 2):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
output = doc.css('div h3 a').map{|x| x['href']}
```

You can use something like `map` to capture all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
output = doc.css('div h3 a')
```

`output.class`  # => Nokogir::XML::NodeSet

Nokogir::XML::NodeSet is an "Array like" class, so(taking it simple) you can expect Nokogir::XML::NodeSet objects to behave like Arrays when standard iterate methods or [] is called on it.

In your example output contains all occurrences of an:
  **a** tags being within **h3** tags which in turn are within **div** tags.(2 hits)

so you can:

`output[0].attr('href')` # => "http://www.faith.co.uk/"
`output[1].attr('href')` # => "http://www.hate.co.uk/"

```
output.each do |node|
  puts "Link says: " + node.content
end
```

Link says: Rodeo Sinclair
 Link says: Morvern

```
output.map do |node|
  node.attr('href')
end
```

# => ['http://www.faith.co.uk/', 'http://www.hate.co.uk/']
and so on...

go and check nokogiri.org for more examples and in depth explanations.